# チェックボックスをJavascriptでチェックできてもinput type="checkbox" の後にcheckedが付かない

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, selenium

Python、seleniumで社内サイトをスクレイピングしているのですが、チェックボックスにチェックをいれてから、押すボタン【確定ボタン】があります。

そこで、seleniumでそのサイトまでアクセスしたのち、下記のスクリプトでチェックボックスにチェックを入れようと考えました。

```
script = 'document.querySelector("チェックボックスのCSSセレクタ").checked = true;'
driver.execute_script(script)
```

しかし、一時的にチェックは付くのですが、HTMLを確認してみたところ、`input type="checkbox"` の後に**checked**と付いてくれません。

Checkedと付かなければ画面をスクロールして戻したらチェックは消えてしまいます。
そのため【確定ボタン】を押してもなにも反応せず、、、。

もちろん`.click()`でならチェックは付き、`input type="checkbox"` の後に**checked**と付いてくれるのですが、`.click()`を使用するとHTMLが変わってしまいcssセレクタがズレてしまうので使いたくありません。

煩雑な質問で申し訳ございませんが、何卒、宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: `python`,`selenium`のタグが付いているのは何故でしょう？ `html`,`css`,`JavaScript`系の話のようにも見えます。[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に、他の人が問題を検証・調査出来るようなソースとか問題の再現手順を追記してみてください。

Comment: `.click()` で checked 属性は付かないはずですし、checked 属性がなくてもスクロールしたぐらいでチェック状態は変わらないはずです。そのあたりもう一度確認してください。

Comment: `checked` はあくまで **HTML 側で** 予めチェックしておくための記述であり、ブラウザからの操作で記述を書き換えることは基本的にできません (UserScriptなど無理やり書き換える方法もあるでしょうが、今回は対象外でしょう) / 根本的なところで何か思い違いをされている可能性があります。

Comment: @int32_t 様
下記、.click()ならcheckedが付いて、上記スクリプトで実行すると、スクロールしたらチェックは外れてしまいました。

Comment: @cubick 様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
やはりクリックでやるしかないのですかね、、、
checked属性を付けたいだけなのですが、、、

Comment: 「HTMLを確認してみた」というのは、どのような操作をして、何をどう確認したのでしょうか？　具体的に教えてください。

Comment: @Fumu7 様
ご連絡ありがとうございます。
chrome driverをつかってスクレイピングしておりまして、
チェックをつけたタイミングでpythonを一時停止し、
chromeでF12を押してinput type="checkbox" の後にcheckedが付いているか見ています。手順としては正しいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

簡単な話フォーム自体がファンクションで動いてると思うので1番確認した方がいいかもしれないのがJavaで実際にほんとにそのIDを選択してチェックをしてるのか、他のところを見てチェックしてるのか、またはブラインドでチェックしているのかを確認するのが良いかと思いますよ。